# Oracle Database client error

Tags: asp.net, database, oracle, visual-studio-2012

I have 64bit windows and I have Visual studio 2012 also 64bit. I have installed the 64-bit Oracle client, but I am getting this message when I try to connect to my database server..

> Attempt to load oracle client libraries threw badimageformatexception. This problem will occur when running in 64bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed at DataObjectSupport(721,6)

Any solutions?

Comment: then you must have somewhere the 32 bit Oracle drivers installed - probably before installing the 64 Bit ones...

Comment: The problems is that I don't .... and I have no idea how to uninstall this ..

Comment: You can use the Oracle installer to uninstall Oracle components...

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio IDE (at least 2012 and below) is 32bit, not 64bit.

If you check the path, you will it runs from:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

not, from "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0".

Therefore, to connect to an Oracle database from the IDE itself, you need the 32bit client installed (in addtion to the 64bit client, if you need it for x64 apps).